# How to replace empty string with a default string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to replace an empty string (`''`) and not `None` with the separate string. `Replace` and `regex_replace` are not good in this case. How can I achieve this without doing double computation like using an `IFF` condition or `LEN` function to first calulcate the length and do the same computation if len is not zero.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

> "How can I achieve this without doing double computation like using an IFF condition or LEN function to first calulcate the length and do the same computation if len is not zero."

The description is vague, but I guess you don't want to repeat the code twice and achieve sth like:

```
SELECT IFF(really_complex_computation > ..., if_true, sth(really_complex_computation))
```

Please keep in mind that modern query optimizers could do a calculation once even when defined twice.

---

Normaly with SQL you could do it with cte:

```
WITH cte (
   SELECT complex_computation AS complex_computation_result, ...
   FROM ...
)
SELECT IIF(complex_computation_result > 0, if_true, sth(complex_computation_result)
FRON cte ...;
```

or with LATERAL:

```
SELECT *, IIF(complex_computation_result > 0, if_true, sth(complex_computation_result))
FROM ...,
LATERAL (SELECT complex_computation AS complex_computation_result) s;
```